# javax.annotation.PreDestroy class not found in lenskit and jdk 10

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, annotations, classnotfoundexception

I'm working with lenskit and I receive this error

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.grouplens.grapht.LifecycleManager.registerComponent(LifecycleManager.java:52)
    at org.grouplens.grapht.reflect.internal.ClassInstantiator.instantiate(ClassInstantiator.java:140)
    at org.grouplens.grapht.Instantiators$ProviderInstantiator.instantiate(Instantiators.java:148)
    at org.grouplens.grapht.Instantiators$MemoizingInstantiator.instantiate(Instantiators.java:184)
    at org.lenskit.inject.NodeInstantiator$DefaultImpl.instantiate(NodeInstantiator.java:91)
    at org.lenskit.inject.NodeInstantiator.apply(NodeInstantiator.java:70)
    at org.lenskit.inject.NodeInstantiator$DefaultImpl.apply(NodeInstantiator.java:82)
    at org.lenskit.inject.InstantiatingNodeProcessor.processNode(InstantiatingNodeProcessor.java:54)
    at org.lenskit.inject.NodeProcessors.processNodes(NodeProcessors.java:92)
    at org.lenskit.inject.RecommenderInstantiator.replaceShareableNodes(RecommenderInstantiator.java:113)
    at org.lenskit.inject.RecommenderInstantiator.instantiate(RecommenderInstantiator.java:82)
    at org.lenskit.LenskitRecommenderEngineBuilder.build(LenskitRecommenderEngineBuilder.java:144)
    at org.lenskit.LenskitRecommenderEngineBuilder.build(LenskitRecommenderEngineBuilder.java:112)
    at org.lenskit.cli.util.RecommenderLoader.loadEngine(RecommenderLoader.java:87)
    at org.lenskit.cli.commands.GlobalRecommend.execute(GlobalRecommend.java:72)
    at org.lenskit.cli.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 16 more
```

It says that the annotation.PreDestroy class wasn't found. But in my external library there is a java.xml.ws.annotation library which includes the javax.annotation file.

The place that it was called is here.

```
    /**
 * Register a component with the lifecycle manager.  The component will be torn down when the lifecycle manager
 * is closed, using whatever teardown the lifecycle manager institutes.
 *
 * @param instance The component to register.
 */
public void registerComponent(Object instance) {
    if (instance == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (instance instanceof AutoCloseable) {
        actions.add(new CloseAction((AutoCloseable) instance));
    }
    for (Method m: MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation(instance.getClass(), PreDestroy.class)) {
        actions.add(new PreDestroyAction(instance, m));
    }
}
```

I'm currently using intellij, and I've tried importing the [javax.annotation jar file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2) but it didnt work. I also tried putting this code

```
dependencies {
compileOnly group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.0'
compile group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '15.0'
```

}

but it still didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at lenskit source on GitHub, it declares `sourceCompatibility = '1.7'` in [build,gradle](https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit-hello/blob/master/build.gradle#L4).
Downgrading JDK to 8 or 7 should do the trick and resolve the issue. since javax.annotations.PreDestroy seem to have been removed/updated in JDK 9 and later.

Beyond that, there may be other compatibility issues with a later JDK version due to the project's source compatibility mentioned above.

Comment: Why on earth should you downgrade... The classes have been moved to external libraries as they aren't part of the core JDK anymore. Include the appropriate dependencies instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum the project being discussed specifies sourceCompatibility = '1.7' in build.gradle.
Would it not be better to use an earlier version of JDK to avoid other compatibility issues?

Comment: It discusses JDK 10. There is no notion of a sourceCompatibility in the question whatsoever.

Comment: The question is about lenskit ("I'm working with lenskit and I receive this error").
lenskit is an open source project, and it contains the build.gradle file which specifies sourceCompatibility = '1.7'. See here: https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit-hello/blob/master/build.gradle#L4
I will update my answer to highlight this more explicitly. Unless I am missing something I think for users of lenskit, using JDK7 or 8 is preferred, at least until lenskit is updated to compatibility with more recent JDK.

Comment: source compatibility says nothing about target compatibility. And the question has nothing to do with lens kit (at least not the error).